# Web Service to get Fuel Prices in Java App WADL

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm making an android application. For one part of my application I just need an average gas price and I would like it to be live rather than static. I don't even need to it to be within a zip code, a national average will be fine.

fueleconomy.gov offers a WADL web service
http://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/ws/index.shtml#fuelprices

I have no idea how to implement that in my java code to simply return the gas price. I've done a lot of searching and can't come to the conclusion if a WADL can be used with JAVA or not? I don't want to create my own service, just consume the above one.

Any ideas that can push me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for [consuming RESTful webservices in java](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=consuming%20restful%20web%20services%20java&aq=0&oq=consuming%20restful&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3.8443j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Code below should get you started:

```
   String url ="http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/31873";     
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
   Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
   NodeList resultList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xmlTagYouWantToAccess");
```

Comment: Yep, and run this on an `AsyncTask`, or you'll get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in Android 4.x+.